# How would I remove the text before the initial period, the initial period itself and text after final period in a string?

Tags: r, regex, string

I need to remove the text before the leading period (as well as the leading period) and the text following the last period from a string.

Given this string for example:

```
"ABCD.EF.GH.IJKL.MN"
```

I'd like to get the output:

```
[1] "IJKL"
```

I have tried the following:

```
split_string <- sub("^.*?\\.","", string)

split_string <- sub("^\\.+|\\.[^.]*$", "", string)
```

I believe I have it working for the period and text after for that string output I want. However, the first line needs to be executed multiple times to remove the text before that period in question e.g. '.I'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option in `base R` is to capture as a group  (`(...)`) the word followed by the dot (`\\.`) and the word (`\\w+`) till the end (`$`) of the string.  In the replacement, use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured word

```
sub(".*\\.(\\w+)\\.\\w+$", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "IJKL"
```

Here, we match characters (`.*`) till the `.` (`\\.` - escaped to get the literal value because `.` is a metacharacter that will match any character if not escaped), followed by the word captured (`(\\w+)`), followed by a dot and another word at the end (`$`)of the string.  The replacement part is mentioned above

---

Or another option is `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
regmatches(str1, regexpr("\\w+(?=\\.\\w+$)", str1, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "IJKL"
```

---

Or another option is `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(str1, -2, sep="[.]")
#[1] "IJKL"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "ABCD.EF.GH.IJKL.MN"
```

Comment: Thanks so much @akrun! They both work great! Could you provide a little more detail on what is happening in the first regex example you gave here!

Comment: @Lynda Thanks, I updated the post with some description. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @akrun for the clarity!

Answer (score 0):

These alternatives all use no packages or regular expressions.

**1) basename/dirname** Assuming the test input  `s` shown in the Note at the end convert the dots to slashes and then use `dirname` and `basename`.

```
basename(dirname(chartr(".", "/", s)))
## [1] "IJKL" "IJKL"
```

**2) strsplit**  Using `strsplit` split the strings at dot creating a list of character vectors, one vector per input string, and then for each such vector take the last 2 elements using `tail` and the first of those using indexing.

```
sapply(strsplit(s, ".", fixed = TRUE), function(x) tail(x, 2)[1])
## [1] "IJKL" "IJKL"
```

**3) read.table** It is not clear from the question what the general case is but if all the components of s have the same number of dot separated fields then we can use `read.table` to create a data.frame with one row per input string and one column per dot-separated component.  Then take the column just before the last.

```
dd <- read.table(text = s, sep = ".", as.is = TRUE)
dd[[ncol(dd)-1]]
## [1] "IJKL" "IJKL"
```

**4) substr** Again, the general case is not clear but if the string of interest is always at character positions 12-15 then a simple solution is:

```
substr(s, 12, 15)
## [1] "IJKL" "IJKL"
```

### Note

```
s <- c("ABCD.EF.GH.IJKL.MN", "ABCD.EF.GH.IJKL.MN")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @G.Grothendieck! Could you provide a little more detail on what everything means in your code in question 2 and 3 here!

Comment: Have expanded the discussion.  Suggest running the parts of the answer separately to further investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Split into groups at period and take the second one from last.

```
sapply(strsplit(str1, "\\."), function(x) x[length(x) - 1])
#[1] "IJKL"
```

---

Get indices of the periods and use `substr` to extract the relevant portion

```
sapply(str1, function(x){
    ind = gregexpr("\\.", x)[[1]]
    substr(x, ind[length(ind) - 1] + 1, ind[length(ind)] - 1)
}, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "IJKL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a janky dplyr version in case the other values are of importance and you want to select them later on, just include them in the "select".

```
df<- data.frame(x=c("ABCD.EF.GH.IJKL.MN"))
df2<-df %>%
  separate(x, into=c("var1", "var2","var3","var4","var5")) %>%
  select("var4")
```